# How to get the output of a command in Deno?

Tags: deno

For example, suppose I have the following code:

```
Deno.run({cmd: ['echo', 'hello']})
```

How do I collect the output of that command which is `hello` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Deno.run` returns an instance of [`Deno.Process`](https://deno.land/api@v1.25.3?s=Deno.Process). Use the method `.output()` to get the buffered output.
Don't forget to pass `"piped"` to `stdout`/`stderr` options if you want to read the contents.

```js
const cmd = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["echo", "hello"], 
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped"
});

const output = await cmd.output() // "piped" must be set

cmd.close(); // Don't forget to close it
```

`.output()` returns a `Promise` which resolves to a `Uint8Array` so if you want the output as a UTF-8 string you need to use `TextDecoder`

```js
const outStr = new TextDecoder().decode(output); // hello
```